# Change how big a pixel is in an image

Tags: gimp

I have an image which I am trying to adjust by moving some parts, but when I try to move a certain part, even when I'm zoomed in as far as possible, the most precisely I can move it is by one pixel. However, for my image, moving by one pixel is too big. Is there a way to redefine the pixel size so that I can make even smaller adjustments and movements?

I thought that Scale Image -> X/Y Resolution would do that, but even with a much higher resolution one pixel is still the same width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a physical pixel in a screen, a digital image pixel has no specific size. It can be as large or small as you want by defining the image's ppi. A 100 x 100 pixel image at 300 ppi, is no bigger than a 100 x 100 pixel image at 72 ppi. 100 pixels = 100 pixels regardless of how big you stretch them.

A digital pixel is the smallest editable element of an image. In order to manipulate smaller sections, you have to raise the resolution with resampling so that the existing pixels are divided. For example, if you have an image that is 100 x 100 pixels, and you wanted to manipulate something smaller than one pixel, you could increase the resolution (with resampling) to 200 x 200. This would split each pixel into 4 new pixels. Then the image would seem to be composed of smaller pixels, but really the image would just be enlarged over 4 times the pixels. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks...as it turns out, the problem was that as I was increasing the ppi, GIMP was decreasing the size of the image at the same time. If I then re-increased the size of the image I was able to achieve the desired effect.